# Delete an object from a base class pointer

Tags: c++

Imagine I have two class *A* and *B* defined like this :

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void pureVirtual() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
public: 
    virtual void pureVirtual();
}
```

I have of course other methods, but that's just for the example. Now, in my cpp code I have this kind of var :

```
B *myB = new B;
A *myA = myB;
```

Is it possible to delete *myB* object by calling delete on *myA* like this : `delete myA;` ? Do I have to do something special to be able to do that ?
Is it okay with OOP ideas and programming style, or a very bad idea ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but `A` needs a virtual destructor for this to work correctly:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void pureVirtual() = 0;
    virtual ~A() {}
}
```

From an OO-perspective there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: +1, but it only needs a virtual destructor... well, if needed :)

Comment: +1. Not only possible, but quite normal; see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7. It suggests that you "make your destructor `virtual` if your class has *any* `virtual` functions."

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker:  The code `A* a = new B; delete a;` evokes UB if `A` doesn't have a virtual destructor, regardless of whatever else `A` and `B` do..

Comment: I would say that not only is there nothing wrong with this from an OO-persepctive, but very often there **is** something wrong with it if you don't do this in OO programming.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the Base's destructor as virtual will make sure that the derived's destructor will be called as well and before it.
I always define the destructor as virtual when I know I'm planning on having Base* to Derived objects.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to **always** define a virtual dtor when inheriting.  It could make your class polymorphic when what you really want is a POD.  Long story short, there is no "always" in programming.

Comment: @John You're correct. I've edited my answer to emphasize what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The only think you have to do is make the **destructor** virtual in the base class